# Building a searchable/filtering database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am building a searchable database that will be able to be filtered by JS using classes.

When I write my items to put into my mysql database, will I be able to assign classes, or 'tags' to an item so I can for example, hide all items with out this 1 tag/class?

I have made a few that work offline with the items just using divs in HTML but will need to this to be dynamic.

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_products (Type, Size, Material, Price) VALUES ('Toy', '15inch', 'Glass', '50')";
```

Is this the correct syntax for me to later come in and use JS to 'show' only toys that are made of glass? or other types of filtering?

Comment: Can you please explain a little more clearly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to build a database of products, that using ajax, will display them to the web page on load. I want to use JS to target certain classes of these items to filter them. ie: "Show only glass products" would hide products made of wood and metal.

Comment: Almost  anything can be done, providing you know the technologies you're working with, well enough to consider the logic of implementation.. This question on the other hand, shows you have not considered logic

Comment: I am primarily a front end designer and am trying to pick up something new, I have made a few things that sort of relate to this, but are very robust and am looking for a simpler answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to be able to filter items based on their defined attributes only then you should not use tags. Simple SQL queries will do in this case. If you want items to be filtered based on non-attribute values then you can use tags(like transparent for glass items)